# Linux home dir has a "duplicate" under /home/music but when anything is deleted from one it disappears from both -- how can I delete 2nd home dir?

Tags: home, delete, duplicate

I don't know where the 2nd "phantom" home dir came from. Properties folder shows it's 4K. The "real" home directory is 128,000+ files and 208GB.

User10489 had the answer: a symlink directory. In fact, using the ls -l he suggested, I found a second directory that was also a symlink. I used rm to remove both. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you found a symlink

Comment: Agreed. At  www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=files-deleting-links  IBM says: "To delete a file that is a symbolic link, you enter rm against the symbolic link name. This removes the link, not the file it refers to." So I switched to randy/Music/randy and typed: rm MyFile.png

  That removed the symlink in ~/Music/randy AND it removed ~/randy/MyFile.png (the original file), which is what happens when I delete a symlink in Dolphin. I will try to find another way to delete a symlink while leaving the original file untouched.

Comment: You are probably looking in the wrong place.  The directory itself is probably a symlink.  Use the `ls -ld` command to examine them or just `ls -l` in the parent directory, and look for a `l` in the first column and the link target at the end of the line after `->`